# Links to Starting Strength

Tags: discussion

There are many questions on this site like the following.

I want bigger (X). When should I do (thing that does not really make a difference because it is a minutia detail)?

There are 2 ways question like this get answered usually both.

1. With statements that are generally accepted to be true (i.e. drink your protein shake after you work out)
2. Provide a link to Starting Strength.

If the general consensus is that he question is BS and that the OP should just do Starting Strength can we down vote the question and close it?

Answer (score 1):

If the question is "I want to get big and strong" with no other specifics then I vote to close as a duplicate of [this question](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/6828/i-am-underweight-how-do-i-gain-weight-and-muscle/6836#6836). The principle is to establish one or several fairly comprehensive answers to the common question, then link to that question over and over so people see it before they ask.

If the person wants to embiggen a specific body part, e.g. "I want bigger triceps" or whatever, then generally we see a lot of answers that address it specifically, e.g. "do dips". I think that's fine. It would be really cool if someone wrote an extensive answer saying, basically, "you're too much of a noob to worry about bigger triceps; get big and strong all over before worrying about your triceps". I'd upvote and link to such an answer if it were definitive and well-written.

If the question is about a specific detail, e.g. "I want bigger triceps, so should I shake my whey protein or stir it?" then yeah, downvote, vote to close, and make a definitive answer that you link to every time.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend just marking it as a duplicate of a high quality answer, if that's indeed the case. Often there are subtleties like age, sex, goals, and access to a barbell.

Taking it a step further, "drink your protein shake after you work out" is something I hear all the time but I'm not much of a believer in it and would argue that overall nutrition is far more important than the perhaps micro-optimized gainz that are touted via the supplement industry.

I'm not really trying to argue that, but rather to say that even widely held beliefs often aren't *that* widely held.